# Remove event from ViewModel when the User Control is unloading

Tags: c#, wpf, events

In my code, I am attaching an event at my VM to a method at the user control during at loaded event, now I want to remove the event when the user control is unloaded, how can I do it?

At VM

```
public delegate bool CheckCondition();
public class VMClass
{
     event CheckCondition Check;
}
```

at user control

```
public partial class AControl:UserControl
{
   public AControl()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += (s, e) =>
           VM.Check +=() => CheckingCode();
   }
   public VMClass VM => (VMClass)DataContext;
}
```

I am thinking about using UnLoaded event, but the problem is that at the UnLoaded event, DataContext is already null, so I can't unsubscribe the event, ie:

```
   UnLoaded +=(s, e) =>
               VM.Check -=() => CheckingCode();
```

Doesn't work because `VM` is already a `null` at `UnLoaded` .

How can I remove the event attached to `VM.Check` when the user control is unloaded?

Comment: you must not use event in the viewmodel ; but going with Messenger.Register / Send like described below _ so you won't get dead link      https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/how-to-send-string-and-content-messages-with-mvvm-light-messenger/

Comment: Just a side note: the events should follow the `EventHandler` delegate pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataContextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

```
DataContextChanged += (object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    var oldVM = e.OldValue as VMClass;
    var newVM = e.NewValue as VMClass;

    if (oldVM != null)
    {
        oldVM.Check -= CheckingCode;
    }

    if (newVM != null)
    {
        newVM.Check += CheckingCode;
    }
}
```